# Splitting Sentences into Words when Formatting Tags are Present

Tags: regex

I use the following regex to split sentences into words:

```
"('?\w[\w']*(?:-\w+)*'?)"
```

For example:

```
import re
re.split("('?\w[\w']*(?:-\w+)*'?)","'cos I like ice-cream")
```

gives:

```
['', "'cos", ' ', 'I', ' ', 'like', ' ', 'ice-cream', '!']
```

However, formatting tags sometimes appear in my text and my regex obviously can't process them as I would like:

```
re.split("('?\w[\w']*(?:-\w+)*'?)","'cos I <i>like</i> ice-cream!")
```

gives:

```
['', "'cos", ' ', 'I', ' <', 'i', '>', 'like', '</', 'i', '> ', 'ice-cream', '!']
```

while I would like:

```
['', "'cos", ' ', 'I', ' <i>', 'like', '</i> ', 'ice-cream', '!']
```

How would you go about solving this?

Comment: Just curious, why are you keeping those empty strings such as `''`, or `'  '`?

Comment: @ccf Because then I know that the odd numbered elements are words and that the even are not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a word boundary regex, specifying exclusions of matches using negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions:

```
^|(?<!['<\/-])\b(?![>-])
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vH2qZ8/1)

Unfortunately, the python regex engine doesn't support [splitting on zero-width characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988595/python-regex-splitting-on-pattern-match-that-is-an-empty-string), so you have to use a workaround.

```
import re

a = re.sub(r"^|(?<!['<\/-])\b(?![>-])", "|", "'cos I <i>like</i> ice-cream!").split('|');
print(a)

#  ['', "'cos", ' ', 'I', ' <i>', 'like', '</i> ', 'ice-cream', '!']
```

[Python demo.](https://repl.it/CK2P/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
# I added a negative lookahead to your pattern to assert bracket > is closed properly

import re
print re.split("('?\w[\w']*(?:-\w+)*'?(?!>))","'cos I <i>like</i> ice-cream!" )

[Output]

['', "'cos", ' ', 'I', ' <i>', 'like', '</i> ', 'ice-cream', '!']
```