# python re.split() empty string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

The following example is taken from the [python re documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)

```
re.split(r'\b', 'Words, words, words.')
['', 'Words', ', ', 'words', ', ', 'words', '.']
```

'\b' matches the empty string at the beginning or end of a word. Which means if you run this code it produces an error.

(jupyter notebook python 3.6)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-f4d2d57a2022> in <module>
      1 reg = re.compile(r"\b")
----> 2 re.split(reg, "Words, word, word.")

/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, flags)
    210     and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
    211     of the list."""
--> 212     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
    213 
    214 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):

ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
```

Since \b only matches empty strings, split() does not get its requirement "non-empty" pattern match. I have seen varying questions related to split() and empty strings. Some I could see how you may want to do it in practice, example, the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988595/python-regex-splitting-on-pattern-match-that-is-an-empty-string). Answers vary from "just can't do it" to (older ones) "it's a bug".

My question is this:

1. Since this is still an example on the python web page, should this be possible? is it something that is possible in the bleeding edge release?
2. The question in the in the link above involved 
   `re.split(r'(?<!foo)(?=bar)', 'foobarbarbazbar')`, it was asked in 2015 and there was no way to accomplish the requirements with just `re.split()`, is this still the case?

Comment: Do you want to split at the start of words? Sorry, but splitting with `\b` does not make much sense. Note that with Python 3.7, you may split with zero length matches.

Comment: Its more about splitting on empty strings. Would the other question in the link be possible with Python 3.7. I used the \b example because it was on the web page, and suggested this type of thing should be possible. Although splitting \b might not be practical, a case where you want to split a long string on an empty match seems like something that might be useful. This example fails for the same reason: re.split(r'(?<!foo)(?=bar)', 'foobarbarbazbar'). I would read this as "split on empty string followed by 'bar' and not prefixed with foo" (could be wrong).

Comment: used this to split words r"\b\W+\b" and this to mimic (not precisely) \b example r"(\b\W+\b)"

Comment: I got `['foobar', 'barbaz', 'bar']` with `re.split(r'(?<!foo)(?=bar)', 'foobarbarbazbar'` in Python 3.7.

Comment: Cool, guess that answers both. All possible with the bleeding edge (3.7).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what answer you expect. Could you please specify what exactly the answer should contain?

Comment: Sorry if that came over wrong. Your comment answers the question. It is something that is possible in the latest python release and the foo bar example can now be done with split in the latest python release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Python 3.7 `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), you can split with zero-length matches:

> *Changed in version 3.7*: Added support of splitting on a pattern that could match an empty string.

Also, note that

> Empty matches for the pattern split the string only when not adjacent to a previous empty match.
>
> ```
> >>> re.split(r'\b', 'Words, words, words.')
> ['', 'Words', ', ', 'words', ', ', 'words', '.']
> >>> re.split(r'\W*', '...words...')
> ['', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '', '']
> ```
>
> >>> re.split(r'(\W*)', '...words...')
> ['', '...', '', '', 'w', '', 'o', '', 'r', '', 'd', '', 's', '...', '', '', '']

Also, with

`re.split(r'(?<!foo)(?=bar)', 'foobarbarbazbar')`

I get `['foobar', 'barbaz', 'bar']` result in Python 3.7.